# SPARQL Insert Into New Graph

Tags: sparql, rdf, named-graphs

I'm new to SPARQL/graph databases and am trying to insert some data into a new named graph in my graph database.

```
INSERT
{ GRAPH graphs:new_graph { ?code groups:memberOfGroup graphs:personGroup } } where 
{?code a obib:CRID .
 ?code obib:denotes ?person .
 ?person a obib:homoSapien .}
```

When I run this query, the graph "new_graph" is created but it contains no data. If I run the same query with a SELECT statement, it returns the data that it should, so the problem is likely in the INSERT section of the query.

Comment: which triple store do you use?

Comment: When I wrote this question, I was using Stardog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope that the problem as been fixed since, but for the sake of it, it should work, could you provide a set of data like this (if I understand your intention):

creation of the test data, a graph `<http://example/shelf_A>` is created with two resources, an author and a book referring to this author:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

INSERT DATA {
    # create graph <http://example/shelf_A> if it doesn't exist
    GRAPH <http://example/shelf_A> {
        # add triple (http://example/author, name, author)
        <http://example/author> dcterms:name "author" .

        # add triples (http://example/book, title, book)
        # and         (http://example/book, author, http://example/author)
        <http://example/book> dcterms:title "book" ;
                              dcterms:author <http://example/author> .  
    } 
}
```

we create a second graph with the books referring to this author and state that they are in the previous graph:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
INSERT
{
  # create graph is it doesn't exist
  GRAPH <http://example/shelf_B> {
    # add the triple (?bood, provenance, http://example/shelf_A)
    # ?book comes from the request below
    ?book dcterms:provenance <http://example/shelf_A> 
  } 
}
WHERE
{
  # select all books (?book) which have an author
  # and this author is named "author"
  ?book dcterms:author ?author .
  ?author dcterms:name "author"
}
```

the result are two graphs:

graph `http://example/shelf_A`:

```
http://example/author  dcterms:name          author
http://example/book    dcterms:author        http://example/author
http://example/book    dcterms:title         book
```

graph `http://example/shelf_B`:

```
http://example/book    dcterms:provenance    <http://example/shelf_A>
```